# Has the drought also revealed ancient structures in France as it did in Ireland?

Tags: ancient-history, france, archaeology

I was wondering whether the drought has also revealed ancient structures in France as it did in Ireland (see the BBC article *[Dry weather reveals ancient site in Meath's Boyne Valley](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-44801939)*).

I searched the net but couldn't find anything (maybe due to my limited knowledge of French).

Comment: That is quite likely. I read an article in a Dutch newspaper a couple of days ago about ancient structures now becoming visible in the landscape due to the drought.

Comment: I haven't heard anything specific about discoveries in France, but the phenomenon of [parch marks](http://www.pastperfect.org.uk/archaeology/parchmarks.html) is not new, and I have no doubt that French archaeologists will also be making the most of the opportunity presented by the drought and carrying out aerial surveys to locate possible features in the landscape.

Comment: A search on Google France hasn't turned up anything...except a report on [UK finds](https://www.anguillesousroche.com/histoire/la-secheresse-au-royaume-uni-revele-des-traces-inedites-de-monuments-historiques/)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem like it in recent years. If you run cursory google searches, along the lines of "drone france structures préhistoriques" or "drone france sécheresse sites archéologiques" and so forth, you end up with plenty of results that relate to the Irish and British findings from the year you asked, but nothing stands out as new in France in 2018. The closest I found using the date-based filters was a 2017 article that [suggested using drones](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/314239012_L%27utilisation_des_micro-drones_pour_la_prospection_archeologique_a_basse_altitude) for this very purpose.

Comment: Thank you Denis for your reply.